# Accessing Json data through URL which needs authenticated

Tags: php, json

I can not seem to find many longer tutorials or resources on how to fully manipulate Json data through PHP. It appears mostly everything is easily done through a few functions etc. However what I cant seem to find is how to access a Json URL that is password protected and needs authenticated.

For example I would like to access a link such as http://armchairanalysis.com/api/1.0/game/1200/conversions but it needs authentication which I have obviously. But unsure of how to go about adding the authentication to the code.

Right now I have

```
$url ='http://armchairanalysis.com/api/1.0/game/1200/conversions';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$characters = json_decode($data);

echo $characters[10]->;
```

That code is easy, just unsure of the authentication part.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This API required HTTP basic authentication to access. The proper way to do this is wrapping the `file_get_contents` function in a HTTP context

```
$url ='http://armchairanalysis.com/api/1.0/game/1200/conversions';

// provide your username and password here
$auth = base64_encode("username:password");

// create HTTP context with basic auth
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth"]
]);

// query for data
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$username="username";
$password="password";
$url="example.com";
$context = stream_context_create(array(
  'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
        )
    ));
$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
print_r(json_decode($json));
```